# An estimate for the logarithmic function

Tags: functions

Does the estimate $|\log x-\log y|\leq K|x-y|$, for any $x$,$y>0$ hold, where K is a positive constant?

Comment: What happens when we choose $y$ close to zero?

Comment: $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^+}\log y=-\infty$. So the answer is clearly no. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Away from $0$, that is, on $[c, \infty)$ the inequality holds by the mean value theorem as the derivative is bounded. But if you consider the log function on $(0, \infty)$, then as user45878 pointed out the LHS of the inequality blows up.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The given inequality is equivalent to say that the derivative of the $\ln$ function is bounded on $(0,\infty)$(why?) which is false. Conclude.